# How to convert OpenCvSharp.Mat to Emgu.CV.Mat?

Tags: c#, opencv, type-conversion, emgucv

I'm using [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) for image processing, but now I also need some of the features of [Emgu CV](https://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to detect faces in my images.

I have the following minimal example:

```C#
public static void DetectFace(OpenCvSharp.Mat inputImage) {
    var faceDetector = new Emgu.CV.FaceDetectorYN("myTrainingModel", "", new Size(inputImage.Width, inputImage.Height));
    var emguMat = new Emgu.CV.Mat();
    faceDetector.Detect(inputImage, emguMat); // <-- gives error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenCvSharp.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.IInputArray'

    // ... more code
}
```

The error I get is:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'OpenCvSharp.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.IInputArray'

I know the error I get could be solved by converting an `OpenCvSharp.Mat` to an `Emgu.CV.IInputArray`, however I would rather like to know how to convert an  `OpenCvSharp.Mat` to an `Emgu.CV.Mat`. As an `Emgu.CV.Mat` implements the `Emgu.CV.IInputArray` interface and I'm going to need to be able to convert to `Emgu.CV.Mat` later in my code anyway.

Comment: I'd just patch OpenCvSharp, and add the wrapper for `FaceDetectorYN`. There ought to be enough inspiration in the existing code to let you do that. Then, make a pull request to get it upstream. Using two different wrapper libraries for the same native library seems a bit :/ and probably just asking for trouble.